# In XSLT, how do I get the filepath of the xml file of a certain element if that xml file was included with xinclude?

Tags: java, xslt, docbook, xinclude

I have these XML files:

```
master.xml (which uses XInclude to include child1.xml and child2.xml)
child1.xml
child2.xml
```

Both `child1.xml` and `child2.xml` contain a `<section>` element with some text.

In the XSLT transformation, I 'd want to add the name of the file the `<section>` element came from, so I get something like:

```
<section srcFile="child1.xml">Text from child 1.</section>
<section srcFile="child2.xml">Text from child 2.</section>
```

How do I retrieve the values `child1.xml` and `child2.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you turn off that feature, all XInclude processors should add an @xml:base attribute
with the URL of the included file. So you don't have to do anything, it should already be:

```
<section xml:base="child1.xml">Text from child 1.</section>
<section xml:base="child2.xml">Text from child 2.</section>
```

( If you want, you can use XSLT to transform the @xml:base attr into @srcFile. )

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure that once xi:include has been processed, you have a single document (and single infoset) that won't let you determine which URL any given part of the document came from.

I think you will need to place that information directly in the individual included files. Having said that, you can still give [document-uri](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-document-uri) a try, but I think all nodes will return the same URI.